# Can a make a Scala trait with a polymorphic, variable-arity abstract method?

Tags: scala, polymorphism, traits, shapeless

Say I have a Scala trait that does some computation and then calls a polymorphic method on extending classes that might have a different method signature in each class:

```
trait GenericThing {

    val vals: Map[String, Any]

    def doGenericStuff(): Unit = {
        println(f"do some other stuff here on ${vals}")
        doSpecificStuff(vals)
    }

    // what should method signature be?
    def doSpecificStuff(vals: Any*)
}

class SpecificThing extends GenericThing {

    val vals = Map(
        "count"  -> 3,
        "animal" -> "rabbit",
        "weight" -> 9.5
    )

    // broken -- doesn't match superclass signature
    def doSpecificStuff(count: Int, animal: String, weight: Double): Unit = {
        println(f"${count} quick brown ${animal}s weigh ${weight * count} pounds")
    }
}
```

I want the `SpecificThing#doSpecificStuff` method to have a proper method signature like `doSpecificStuff(count: Int, animal: String, weight: Double)`, not just a generic one like `doSpecificStuff(vals: Any*)`. It may have a different arity in each implementor of the trait. (If it helps, the *names* of the parameters could be standardized: `doSpecificStuff(a: Int, b: String, c: Double)`).

Is there a way, perhaps using [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) or something like it, to make something like this work?

Comment: How would a user of `GenericThing` know how to use it? since it may be completely different depending on the underlying implementation.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - the idea is that implementing classes (`SpecificThing1`, `SpecificThing2`, etc.) just need to define a `doSpecificStuff` method, and they can count on it to be called with the proper data by the `GenericThing` trait. They just have to implement `vals` and `doSpecificStuff` and that's all they have to know.

Comment: @jwvh - The `vals` map tells the trait what values / types to call `doSpecificStuff` with. There are presumably other ways to handle that, but somehow the trait has to know what (typed) values to pass to the implementing class `doSpecificStuff` method. (My real example is more complicated of course but this is the basic idea.)

Comment: @Sasgorilla some that method will always be an implementation detail? Then why not just reimplement the generic / public one in each class?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - Yep, that's how I do it now. The problem is there's a lot of duplicated, non-business-logic, boilerplate code in that shared `doGenericStuff` method that I don't want to repeat in every implementing class. (Not shown here of course to keep it simple.) I'd like to do that part in a generic, polymorphic way so the implementing classes just worry about the business logic.

Comment: Can you do something like [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/Aq44IuG2RqyYQDXdMscShQ)?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - Thank you, but unfortunately 1) the trait itself needs access to the values as well to do some pre-processing, and 2) in the interest of clean, self-documenting code, I'd like for the method signature on `SpecificThing#doSpecificStuff()` to define the values/types that it needs. So a design with no arguments to `doSpecificStuff` will probably not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Is that `val vals: Map[String, Any]` specifically required ?

How about parameterising the `GenericThing` on input contract of `doSpecificStuff` ?

```scala
trait GenericThing[A] {

  val value: A

  def doGenericStuff(): Unit = {
    println(f"do some other stuff here on ${value}")
    doSpecificStuff(value)
  }

  def doSpecificStuff(value: A)
}
```

Specific Implementation :

```
class SpecificThing1(val value: SpecificThing1.Value) extends GenericThing[SpecificThing1.Value] {
  override def doSpecificStuff(value: SpecificThing1.Value): Unit = {
    println(f"${value.count} quick brown ${value.animal}s weigh ${value.weight * value.count} pounds")
  }

}

object SpecificThing1 {
  final case class Value(count: Int, animal: String, weight: Double)
}
```

Usage:

```scala
val specificThing = new SpecificThing1(SpecificThing1.Value(3, "rabbit", 9.5))

specificThing.doGenericStuff()
// do some other stuff here on SpecificValueThing(3,rabbit,9.5)
// 3 quick brown rabbits weigh 28.5 pounds
```

Comment: `val vals` is definitely not a requirement (and is in fact not in my real-world implementation). It's just a means to an end which I think you've achieved more elegantly here. This is great -- obviously, a little more complicated than the original, but I like how the `Value` case class preserves the shape of the args.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
import shapeless.ops.maps.FromMap
import shapeless.{::, HList, HNil}

trait GenericThing {  
  def vals: Map[String, Any]

  type L <: HList
    
  def doGenericStuff()(implicit fromMap: FromMap[L]): Unit = {
    println(f"do some other stuff here on ${vals}")
    doSpecificStuff(fromMap(vals).getOrElse(???))
  }

  def doSpecificStuff(vals: L): Unit
}

class SpecificThing extends GenericThing {    
  override val vals = Map(
    "count"  -> 3,
    "animal" -> "rabbit",
    "weight" -> 9.5
  )

  override type L = Int :: String :: Double :: HNil

  override def doSpecificStuff(vals: L): Unit = vals match {
    case count :: animal :: weight :: HNil =>
      println(f"${count} quick brown ${animal}s weigh ${weight * count} pounds")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case this point has been missed in all the noise, this pattern simple doesn't work:

```
trait GenericThing {
    def doSpecificStuff(vals: Any*)
}

class SpecificThing extends GenericThing {
    def doSpecificStuff(count: Int, animal: String, weight: Double)
}
```

You cannot override a generic method with a more specific method, because you can call the generic method with arguments that the specific method does not accept.

More generally, it is not a good pattern to have a base class with lots of functionality that calls overridden methods on itself. A better model is to have the generic code delegate the non-generic behaviour to another class that is injected into the implementation, either directly or using a typeclass.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use path-dependent types and value function for that

```
trait GenericThing {
  type I

  def doSpecificStuff(i: I): Unit
}


class SpecificThing extends GenericThing {
  type I = (Int, String, Double) // better be case class

  def doSpecificStuff(tupple: (Int, String, Double)): Unit
}
```